# Object for storing types for use during static analysis

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, pydantic

Is there a way/convention in Python (3.10+) to store types defined in a module, within some container/registry class so that static analysis tools like `mypy` can correctly infer the type of an annotation?

Context for this problem:

- Format standard that in-house packages should use the form `from <package> import X`
- Module in question can have 100+ types
- Consuming module generates 1:1 type for each type in the other module

Starting from the last item, a 1:1 example looks like:

```
from <package> import TypeBase, TypeOne, TypeTwo

class OuterBase:
   attr: TypeBase

class OuterOne:
   attr: TypeOne

class OuterTwo:
   attr: TypeTwo
```

This would become frustrating if I have to import 100+ types, so it would be convenient to have some container that I can reference the types for static analysis similar to an `Enum` but something like `TypeEnum`.

There are two ways that this outcome can be achieved:

- Import the package and using its namespace as the "container"

```
from <package-parent> import <package>

class OuterBase:
   attr: <package>.TypeBase
```

- Create a non-instantiable class holding class attributes with `TypeAlias`

```
# inside <package>

class PackageTypes
  TypeBase: TypeAlias = TypeBase
  TypeOne: TypeAlias = TypeOne
  ...

# inside consumer package

from <package> import PackageTypes

class OuterBase:
   attr: PackageTypes.TypeBase
```

The former breaks the "format standard" imposed on the project that imports should get to their final absolute form (i.e. no in-house packages import in their entirety, only names within modules); this is something I've inherited and cannot change. It would however, be the most idiomatic solution, but it's out of my hands.

The latter is concise, but I have to have hardcoded class with 100+ class attributes that are really just references to types; while not terrible, it seems repetitive and bulky.

Does Python have a native solution given these constraints or perhaps Pydantic 2?

Comment: Forcing `from <package> import TypeBase, TypeOne, TypeTwo` is a terrible standard, monumentally silly. I'm so sorry.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am not in disagreement with you. Recently started on a new team, and this is a company wide format standard (systems won't build unless it passes that check), so hence my question. I am currently using the 2nd option shown, with the worst side-effect being duplication of declaration in the package where they types exist.